# Action redirect() not reset the Model filters

Tags: yii2

How to make my ACTION `actionPosvenda` redirect() not reset the filters that the user made in Gridview previously?

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new DailyproductivitySearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

public function actionPosvenda($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            return $this->renderAjax('posvenda', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @quqoan You can use: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-url#remember-urls

Comment: not clear how you are navigation to the `actionPosvenda` are you using `post` or `get` to submit from the gridview, as the code looks to be using `post`,

Comment: I did not succeed!
In fact I just wanted a way for the user to filter the records defined as "No" in the column "aux_flag_posvenda" and with a single click change it to "Yes" (without undoing the filter).